# Smart contract to send data to requested device

Tags: solidity, raspberry-pi

I have multiple Pi's connected to a miner in a private network, where one pi is collecting sensor data, and am able to send ether from all the devices and they are all synchronised with the private blockchain.

How can a smart contract request data from pi B and Pi A sends the data back automatically

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve can be implemented using an oracle.

- Your smart contract generates an event `RequestData(uint id)`, where `id` can be an identification of the raspberry pi.
- An application is listening for events in your blockchain. When a `RequestData(uint id)` arrives it will make the request to the corresponding raspberry pi.
- When the data is acquired it will be send by the application to your smart contract, for example it will call a function `sendData(id, data)`.